# How to add transparent image on Oracle Reports?

Tags: image, oracle, report, overlay, transparent

In one of my Oracle report, I have 2 images overlay each other and the front image covered part of the image on the back, which is set as watermark.

Is there any way can add transparent image in Oracle Reports?

I have tried make the image transparent in GIF and TIF format, but after load the image to Oracle Reports, the transparent part of the image tuns to black colour instead of no colour (transparent).

I know using Photoshop or other tools to make the front image looks like transparent is a way, but really want to if there is another solution for it.

Any suggestion is welcomed.

Thanks.